# Cannot get error code from GetPrivateProfileString

Tags: c++, winapi

Here is my code.

```
char BPP[5];
int result, err;

result = GetPrivateProfileStringA("abc", "cba", NULL, BPP, 5, "D:\\aefeaf.ini"); // result = 0
result = _get_errno(&err); // result = 0, err = 0
result = GetLastError(); // result = 0
```

And description from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): `In the event the initialization file specified by lpFileName is not found, or contains invalid values, this function will set errorno with a value of '0x2' (File Not Found). To retrieve extended error information, call GetLastError.`

Last parameter is random, the file is not existed. But GetLastError() still return 0. Could someone explain to me why it didn't return 2?

**EDIT:** As @JochenKalmbach suggest, I ensure my project is not using C++/CLI. And @claptrap said that errorno is a typo (it should be [errno](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx)), I add _get_errno to my code above. But still, all the error code return is 0. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: does errorno get set to 2 ? errorno != getlasterror

Comment: @claptrap then where do you suggest me to look for errorno?

Comment: What is the return vaue of "GetPrivateProfileStringA"?

Comment: should be 0, since it normally returns number of characters read and there is no default value.

Comment: `GetPrivateProfileStringA` return 0. `char BPP[5];` is how BPP declared.

Comment: @DzungAh there is a typo of the description, it is not called `errorno` it is called `errno`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t3ayayh1.aspx

Comment: @claptrap: I tried `_get_errno` but it still return 0.

Comment: Works fine on my machine.  Screwing up the value you get from GetLastError() is far too easy.  Make sure the snippet you posted **exactly** matches your code, don't leave stuff out.  We know you left stuff out, surely there are if() statements in the real code.  And do strongly consider not using it, GetPrivateProfileString() has horrible appcompat behavior that can cause many accidents and is incredibly slow as well.

Comment: Dear @HansPassant, seriously you don't know. I test it on an empy project and the code is **exactly** above. And the result still is screwed.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you are not using C++/CLI... this will mess up the value of "GetLastError" because the code internally uses "IJW" (it just works) and does a bunch of Win32 operations....

FOr native applications, this works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int _tmain(int argv, char *argc[]) 
{
  char szStr[5];
  int result = GetPrivateProfileStringA("abc", "cba", NULL, szStr, 5, "D:\\aefeaf.ini");
  _ASSERTE(result == 0);
  result = GetLastError();
  _ASSERTE(result == 2);
}
```

If you are using C++/CLI, then you should surround the method with

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
// Place the method here
#pragma managed(pop);
```

Comment: I'm not use C++/CLI, unfortunately. The program is simple dialog-based MFC.

Comment: @DzungAh: For me it works without any problems... have you executed the simple exaple?

Comment: I did create an empty project to test the method, and the result is still the same. I'm using VS2008.

Comment: I have tested it with VS2008/2010 and VS2012... also a bug should not depend on the VS-version... The function is an OS function... so what OS are you using?

Comment: I just think maybe VS enable C++/CLI or smt like that. Nevermind. I'm using Windows XP SP3.

Comment: You can verify C++/CLI support by checking the project properties in "Configuration Properties|General|Common Language Runtime Support" the value must be "No Common Language Runtime Support"

Comment: Thanks. I checked and changed the value to "No Common Language Runtime Support" but the result is still the same.